# Attempting to gather user's IP address with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the user's ip address once the page loads with the following:

```
<?php  
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
?>
```

and trying to print the value like so:

```
<input id="ip" name="ip"  value="<?php $user_ip = echo ($user_ip); ?>" type="hidden">
```

for some reason it won't print. Any ideas?

Comment: try remove `$user_ip =` and just do `echo $user_ip;`

Comment: It should be noted that **anyone** can change the **form value** if they want to. Do not expect the `ip` **form value** to be correct.

Comment: `echo` is a language construct. it has no return value. `$foo = echo ...` is utterly pointless.

Comment: h2o is correct. If you need the value on the server side for some reason (I'm guessing so since it's a hidden input) you should just assign it using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` again not get it from a POSTed form. If you're just displaying it to the user for their own benefit, why is it hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you assign the echo result, it will print nothing :

```
<input id="ip" name="ip"  value="<?php echo ($user_ip); ?>" type="hidden">
```

If you want to display it to user :

```
<input id="ip" name="ip"  value="<?php echo ($user_ip); ?>" type="text">
```

Comment: So how should I write this php in order print the ip address?

Comment: Well you have chosen `type="hidden"`, so it is not displayed to user on the page. If you want to display it, use `type="text"`

Comment: Okay, I see now but it doesn't display an IP address. It just prints the following: <?php echo ($user_ip); ?>

Comment: @J-LO whats the file extension?

Comment: Do you manage to execute `php` on your server ? Because it should work. Is it a `.php` file that you call ?

Comment: Oh no I just embedded it into my html code. I'm new to php. Obviously.

Comment: Try to rename your html page with a `.php` extension. And if you use apache, look if there is `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in your configuration file. Anyway, what is written here works If you still have a problem, it is your web server configuration that fails. ;)